# Windows Login screen to home screen

Tags: windows-10, boot, login

If you start your windows machine you see this wallpaper and the clock in the bottom left corner.

If you click somewhere you go to the login page where you can choose between the users. If you wait about 1 minute it shows you the "welcome screen" again.

Is there a way to instantly go back to the welcome screen? I dont want to wait this 1 minute.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The wallpaper I think you are seeing is the lockscreen, with the clock.  Then clicking or pressing a key will display the login/user options, or just the active logged in user.

You are describing the timeout for the loginui to return to the blank lockscreen.  This belive this can be modified (or added if not configured):

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI
DWORD Value: IdleTimeOut
Unit: msec
```

Disclaimer: UNTESTED - I have not done this myself, as the timeout is adequate for me, about 20 secs, and too short would be harder to login.